# Test & Target not working with AMP or Facebook

Tags: facebook, testing, adobe, target, amp-html

I am running a Facebook ad campaign that links to a page that’s running an A/B test with adobe. If you go to the page via your mobile phone it works just fine, but if you click on it in Facebook the Facebook mobile browser strips ensigbten & adobe code. Is there a reason and/or work around for this?

Comment: I didn't understand the problem (What's ensigbten?). Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

The AMP framework from Google does not allow third party JavaScript execution which would include tag managers like Ensighten or Tealium. I'm not 100% sure but I believe the Facebook framework does something similar. This is done under the auspices of making the pages as fast as possible and lots of third party integrations tend to slow things down.